# How to fix "TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable tanh method"?

Tags: python, math, pde

I am trying to get the nullclines of Morris-Lecar model using the equation and solve commands from sympy module, but it tells me "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable tanh method"
how can I solve this and draw the nullclines?

This is my code

```
import scipy as sp
import sympy as spy
from scipy.integrate import odeint


V, V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4, n , g_Ca, g_K, g_L, C_M, I, V_Ca, V_K, V_L, I, phsi\
    = spy.symbols('V V_1 V_2 V_3 V_4 n  g_Ca g_K g_L C_M I V_Ca V_K V_L I phsi')


def m_infinity(V): return (1.0 + sp.tanh((V - V_1) / V_2)) / 2.0
def n_infinity(V): return (1.0 + sp.tanh((V - V_3) / V_4)) / 2.0
def tau_n(V):   return 1 /( phsi* sp.cosh((V - V_3) / (2*V_4)))
def I_L(V):     return g_L               * (V - V_L) 
def I_K(V, n):  return g_K  * n          * (V - V_K)
def I_Ca(V):    return g_Ca * m_infinity(V) * (V - V_Ca)

### Morris-Lecar Model
dVdt = (I - I_Ca(V) - I_K(V, n) - I_L(V)) / C_M
dndt = (n_infinity(V) - n) / tau_n(V)

###getting the nullclines functions
Vnull = spy.solve(spy.Eq(dVdt,0), n)[0]
nnull = spy.solve(spy.Eq(dndt, 0), n)[0]
print(Vnull)
print(nnull)
```

the output is

> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable tanh method

I want the output to look something like this

```
n = (1.0 + sp.tanh((V - V_3) / V_4)) / 2.0 #which is equal to n_infinity(v)
n  = (I - g_Ca* m_infinity(V)*(V - V_Ca) - g_L*(V - V_L))/((V - V_K)*g_K)
```